# Python Pandas - How to use conditional list comprehension on pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I do have a Pandas Dataframe with only one column. I want to get the index of the dataframe of the first value, where the value exceeds 2.5*sd (a pre-set value). I already do have problems to iterate over the dataframe with a conditionalised list comprehension. It Tells me:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
> a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

My Code is:

```
sd = # some Kind of Formula

x = 2.5*sd

list = [i for i in df['my_column'] if i >= x]

first_val = list[0]
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Cheers!

edit:
The DF Looks like:

```
  my_column
```

0         15.1172

1         15.1172

2         15.1172

3          5.3516

4          5.3516

```
      ...
```

5111     -43.4765

5112       5.3516

5113       5.3516

5114      15.1172

5115      -4.4140

[5116 rows x 1 columns]

float64

Comment: post the sample input. and the code you posted will not cause any error

Comment: What does df['my_column'] look like.

Answer (score 1):

No need of list comprehension here. You can use pandas methods

`df.loc[df['myColumn']>=x].index.tolist()[0]`

Details : `df.loc[df['myColumn']>=x]` gets the df where value in `'myColumn'` is `>= x`. Then you get the list of index and you choose the first one

Comment: you can simplify it a bit and just have `df[df['my_column]>=x].index[0]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's way simpler as I've thought. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simple, as follows:

```
...
list = [i for i in df['my_column'] if i >= x]
first_val = list[0]

first_item_index = int(df[df['my_column']==list[0]].index[0]) # get index of first item with i>=x in dataframe
print(first_item_index)
```